# Set sequence number node & child name in Firebase database with C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in Firebase, I have already upload my sensor data to Firebase real-time database, but the name of every nodes in Firebase are random letters. I want to set these group of data as sequence numbers, like 1,2,3,4,5.....

Here are the code in C#, what should I add to the code?

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://........firebaseio.com/.json");

            request.Method = "PATCH";
            request.ContentType = "Application/json";
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            json = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
```

Hope for any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: To know the next number in such a sequence, you must first know the highest current number in the sequence. This requires that you read from the database before writing the new node. Then you must ensure that the new node doesn't conflict with writes from any other clients. For this reason Firebase recommends against using such sequences, and uses the so-called push IDs that are showing in your screenshot. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason why I want to arrange data as a sequence is i need to read these data in unity, I think with a sequence node name will be more convenient. And I want to know if you know some code about setting Firebase node & child name in C#? thanks.

Comment: I've just described the approach you'll need to take for that.

Comment: Hi, I found another way to implement what I want, thank you anyway.

Comment: If you've found an answer to your own question, please post it below. It might be useful to future developers.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase do not have any prebuilt methods like that, but you can create your logic to get the sequence number working, Simply count the child nodes each time and then add +1 to it to set the next node.

```
  private fun getNextSequentialNumber(completion: (Int) -> Unit) {
    dataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val nextSequentialNumber = dataSnapshot.childrenCount.toInt()+1
            completion.invoke(nextSequentialNumber)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            // Handle error
            println("Error fetching data: $databaseError")
        }
    })
  }
```

and then use it like shown below in your onCreate code

```
    getNextSequentialNumber { nextSequentialNumber ->
        // Use the nextSequentialNumber as needed
        println("Next Sequential Number: $nextSequentialNumber")
    }
```